# CollectionView sort collection with more data types

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, collectionview

I have an underlying ObservableCollection called "Items" which can hold instances of two types (peopleVM, messageVM) via its abstract parent. How to apply a different sort description for each type?

This is my CollectionViewSource:

```c#
var cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);

PropertyGroupDescription groupDescriptionMessages = new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(ISearchedItem.ItemType)); // Group by item type - peoples | messages
cvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescriptionMessages);

cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(ISearchedItem.ItemType), ListSortDirection.Descending)); // Primary sort by Item type - peoples | messages
cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(PeopleVM.ContactName), ListSortDirection.Ascending)); // Sort peoples by name
cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(MessageVM.DateTime), ListSortDirection.Descending)); // Sort messages by date time
```

It is generating couple of BindingExpression in VS output since PeopleVM has no property DateTime and so on...

I need to have something like:

--Header peoples-  // Sorted by name ascending
People 1
People 2

--Header messages--  // Sorted by message date
Message 1
Message 2
Message 3

Comment: Are you saying the collection will contain instances of both types at once, or that sometimes it's all one, and sometimes all the other?

Comment: Yes, both types at once, with different DataTemplates... That is the only way how to solve this problem that i know.

Comment: Right, different DataTemplates is the right thing to do there. But you're not going to be able to provide a different sort description for each type. One option is to write an interface with the union set of properties of the two classes, and have them both implement it. Each class would return constants for unsupported properties -- say there's a date property in messageVM, not in peopleVM; if user sorts by date, peopleVM returns `DateTime.MaxValue` to put them at the end of the sort order.

Comment: Fundamentally, to sort a list `{ p1, m1, p2, m2 }`, you've got to compare p1 to m2 somehow.

Comment: I would probably use [the Filter event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) in this case. For example, in the case of sorting by date, I would want the dateless items last regardless of whether we're sorting by date ascending or descending. I don't think you can express that with `SortDescription`, and you certainly wouldn't want to do something weird like have the dummy properties return different constants depending on a sort order in a view somewhere.

Comment: Finally, i ve ended up with the union set of properties on each type, seems  ugly to me, but works well. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up with using standard SortDescription:

```
cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(ISearchedItem.ContactName), ListSortDirection.Ascending)); // Sort peoples by name
cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(ISearchedItem.DateTime), ListSortDirection.Descending)); // Sort messages by date time
```

This means that I have to add getter only property into implementation of ISearchedItem for sorting purposes only, these properties returns null | DateTime.MaxValue to get rid of BindingExpression error, seem ugly to me, but haven't found better solution yet.